# Ubuntu can't get to Windows folder.

Tags: 14.04

I would like to access Windows/System32 folder from Ubuntu 14.04 (got two systems installed). I can get to partition with Windows but after trying to get to Windows folder the error window appears:

This location can't be displayed. Error while downloading information about "/media/.../Windows/Windows/explorer.exe". Input/output error.

What it means? How can I change this?

Comment: Have you turned of fast boot feature in Windows?

Comment: @TheOneAboveAll yes, I turned it off, but still doesn't work :/